# Why is #frame_end returning a 0 value?

Tags: scripting, shaders, shader-nodes

I'm trying to make a looping animation and want to call the value of my end frame so that I can adjust the length of the animation without breaking the loop. However, when I type #frame_end into the value node, it returns a 0 value (my end frame is 24). `#frame` works as intended, so I'm really not sure why `#frame_end` isn't working as I expect. Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Here's a screenshot of my trash node setup. I was just guessing my way into figuring out how to create a loop, but I realize now this doesn't actually do that. Well, these values do, but that's more or less luck. The code itself doesn't force a perfect loop, which is obviously the desired goal[image]

Edit 2: I think I figured out out the looping issue (still haven't solved the topic question about `frame_end`, but I didn't realize the phases looped by tau, and not 1.

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you are implementing the driver in the scene? I mean, an example of usage... I also would like to point out that while #frame is a "global" variable, the #frame_end it isn't: it belongs to a specific scene, so you should define which scene you are referring to in the driver editor, even if there is only one in the blendfile.

Comment: @Carlo Updated the post with a screenshot. I didn't know that about frame drivers. I've only ever used them a handful of times for super, super basic scenarios. I did look around in the driver editor, but didn't really know what I was looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by *Carlo*, `#frame` creates a driver that uses the global `frame` variable. But `frame_end` is a property of the *Scene* object. If you enter `#frame_end` a driver will be created for you but the expression "*frame_end*" is invalid. To fix this, open the driver editor and enter the correct value.

**Creating a driver to access *scene.frame_end*:**

In the driver editor, add a new variable with the <kbd>+ Add Input Variable</kbd> button if you don't have a valid one.

Give it a name, like `var` in the example. Also, enter this name in the *Expression* box above.

Then look for the *Prop:* setting below. There are two dropdown list boxes right next to it. In the first one (the object type) choose `Scene`, in the second one choose the scene name. The name of the default scene is `Scene`. Now you have the object that you want to access.

Below this there is the *Path:* input box. Here, enter `frame_end` to access the value for the last frame (`250` by default). Now, you should see this value right next to the *Value:* label below, right next to the *Driver Value:* label above, and where you added the driver (purple value). That's it!

[image: driver editor]

**Note:** To get the data path for any Blender setting supported by a driver, simply right-click on it and select *Copy Data Path* from the context menu. For example, hover over the *End Frame* of the timeline and use the context menu entry. You also can enable *Interface (section) > Display > Tooltips >* `[X]` *Python Tooltips* in the *User Preferences* and you will see the data path in the tooltip when you hover over a setting.

Comment: Wow. Thank you sooooo much. This was so informative and easy to follow. I really appreciate the note at the end, too! <3